# How to Print HTML page directly to multi printers using QZ Tray from an MVC app

Tags: model-view-controller, printing, qz-tray

I'm trying QZ Tray from my MVC web app

- I want to print my already generated html page to several printers at once and directly from JS after defining the printers to print on
- The printer is printing a white paper with the file name header only on top

I have read the QZ Quick start and go with several pages of their documentation and tried this:

```html
@{ Layout = null;}

<div>Print test Print test Print test Print test Print test Print test</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/qz-tray.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        qz.websocket.connect({ retries: 5, delay: 1 }).then(function () {
            return qz.printers.find("hp", { margins: 2, orientation: 'portrait' });              // Pass the printer name into the next Promise
        }).then(function (printer) {
            var config = qz.configs.create(printer, { scaleContent: false });       // Create a default config for the found printer
            var data = [{
                type: 'pixel',
                format: 'html',
                flavor: 'plain', // or 'plain' if the data is raw HTML
                data: 'http://localhost:27210/Home/View1',
                options: { pageWidth: 8.5 /* pageHeight: 11 */ }
            }]; return qz.print(config, data);
        }).catch(function (e) { console.error(e); });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> html page to several printers at once and directly

Since 2.1.0 (per [qzind/tray/issues/161](https://github.com/qzind/tray/issues/161#issuecomment-314610362)) you can provide your printers in an array to send the same job to each one.

```js
// ...
var config1 = qz.configs.create("Printer 1", { scaleContent: false }); 
var config2 = qz.configs.create("Printer 2", { scaleContent: false });
var config3 = qz.configs.create("Printer 3", { scaleContent: false }); 
return qz.print([ config1, config2, config3 ], data);
// ...
```

> white paper with the file name header only on top
> (comment) what's wrong on code that it didn't print html page content

If you're providing a URL, you should use `flavor: file`, not `flavor: plain`.  If that still causes problems, ensure the page can be accessed from Incognito Mode/Private Browsing, since QZ Tray requires public access to HTML content.

```js
// ...
            var data = [{
                type: 'pixel',
                format: 'html',
                flavor: 'file', // or 'plain' if the data is raw HTML
//              ^------ HERE
                data: 'http://localhost:27210/Home/View1',
                options: { pageWidth: 8.5 /* pageHeight: 11 */ }
            }]; return qz.print(config, data);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Tresf, I'll try this to print on several printers. Actually this is the second part of the question any body can know what's wrong on code that it didn't print html page content

Comment: I'm trying to print the current page that has the code itself

Comment: @GhaithBezem answer updated.

Comment: Yes, thanks Tresf I've tried flavor: 'file' in my version of the code but it still printing a white page with the file path on header, sorry

Comment: The same from Incognito Mode/Private Browsing still printing white page with header

Comment: I've tried plain flavor with this data: document.getElementById("Normalinvoice").innerHTML it print a srampled page and arabic fonts is showned reversed so not readable, any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to share an HTML example that reproduces the problem for help.  Note, `innertHTML` was deliberately NOT recommended in the answer.  This is because when using this technique, QZ Tray has no page reference and cannot resolve relative paths, everything needs to be inlined to work with 'plain'.  If you cannot share the HTML, I would recommend that you start with a very basic HTML example and make it more complex until it stops working.

Comment: Yes, you're right when I opt out the page it works fine. but it's very strange because when showing the source code of both pages they are identical, I think it has somthing to do with MVC app configuration